# Devanagari font problem - Vedic accents

Tags: fonts, locale

I have installed all devanagri language support packages I can think of, and it works fine most of the time. But, it does not display vedic accents properly:

For example, from [here](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/rigveda/sanskrit03/RV0301.html) :

अ॒ग्निः पूर्वे॑भि॒रृषि॑भि॒रीड्यो॒ नूत॑नैरु॒त।

The anudAttas are not displayed properly on both firefox and chrome. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you viewing from your web browser only, or do you also mean via terminal, office applications, et cetera?

Comment: It works fine in kate, but accents disappear in konsole.

Answer (score 1):

Can you type vedic accents in LibreOffice?

As far as display in browser is concerned, there could be a way to set bitmap fonts for complex text layout, by which you can view any language font in your browser. It can be done in Opera by ticking the related checkbox in config.

Comment: Complex text layout is enabled by default in my firefox 8 (I have no problems reading accent-less devanAgarI.)

Comment: Vedic accents are rendered properly in kate, (not sure about libreoffice.)